# Getting CoreDispatcher in WinForms Classic Desktop app

Tags: c#, winforms, dispatcher

I have a C# WinForms app that scans for bluetooth devices on a background thread.  When it is time to connect to a device, it must call the following method, that must be called on a UI thread:

```
 var btDevice = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(eventArgs.BluetoothAddress);
```

I understand that the way you do this is by encapsulating the above in a async method like `ConnectToBluetoothDevice` and calling it like this:

```
dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => ConnectToBTDevice(args));
```

So far so good.  **My problem is that I cannot get a reference to a CoreDispatcher instance** so I can make the above call.  I have tried a number of ways:

1. Repeatedly calling:

   ```
   try
   {
     dispatcher = Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher;

   }
   catch (System.InvalidOperationException e)
   {
     Console.WriteLine("Cannot get dispatcher yet");
   }
   ```

   The above always falls to the catch block, long after launching the app.
2. Registering for a callback to the Form.Shown callback and then trying to get an instance of the dispatcher from the current UI thread like this:

   ```
   var form = new Form1();
   form.Shown += FormShown;
   Application.Run(form);

   ...

   private static void FormShown(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       var window = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread();
       if (window != null)
       {
           dispatcher = window.Dispatcher;
       }
   }
   ```

   In this case, `window` is always null, which surprises me because the whole point of this callback is that it happens after the form window is shown.  Shouldn't this callback be on the UI thread, and return its CoreWindow?

What am I missing here?  How can I get a CoreDispatcher from a WinForms app?

Comment: I have never done UWP dev, so don't know how it does forms and I may be totally wrong, but doesn't the CoreDispatcher come from the UWP set of libraries and therefore not likely to work with WinForms libraries?

Comment: Have you tried using [Form.Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx) ?  Invoking is typically how you would run code on ui thread in winforms.  There's also [Control.Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all UWP API can be accessed from Classic Desktop applications.

You can refer to this [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt695951(v=vs.85).aspx), which explains that **only API's which have** the `DualApiPartition` attribute can be called from a classic desktop app.

Look at the documentation for [CoreDispatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcher) and you will notice that it **does not support** the `DualApiPartition` attribute.

Alternatively a classic desktop app can refer to the [Dispatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class which is accessible via `WindowsBase.dll` using the `System.Windows.Threading` namespace.

Comment: Yes, using `Dispatcher` instead of `CoreDispatcher` works.  Thanks for the tip about the `DualApiPartition` attribute.   It is a bit frustrating to build a Classic Desktop application that accesses UWP APIs, because most examples assume you are writing a UWP with access to all UWP APIs.  It is not obvious to a novice which UWP APIs will work and which won't (or even know that a particular API is a UWP API at all).  I wish Visual Studio would show a warning, but the `DualApiPartition` attribute at least gives me a way to check when something fails silently.

Comment: @davidgyoung Could you explain in more detail how you got this to work using `Dispatcher`? What did the line of code look like that replaced `dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => ConnectToBTDevice(args));`? I'm having the same problem accessing the UWP Geolocator API in a WPF desktop app because it has to be run from the main UI thread, and have tried switching to `System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher` but it hasn't helped for me.

Comment: I did this instead at init: `self.Dispatcher = System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;`  Then later on: `self.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => ConnectToBTDevice(args));`  I should say, that despite what the documentation says, I see no evidence that making this call must be on the main thread.  On a WinForms Desktop app, I never see a permission request get sent to the user.